# string length comparer

Tags: code-golf, string

this program has to take two strings and compare their length, then tell you which one is longer (`string-a` or `string-b`) and by how much

### rules:

- no using `.length` or other built-in length checking methods (duh!)
- no using addition or subtraction, this includes improvised addition/subtraction, in case you find some sort of weird improvisation.
- no `>` / `<` (greater then/less then) inside `if` / `if-else` statements (you can use them in loops though), this obviously includes `>=` etc. and no cheating (`bool = a > b;if(bool)`)
- emphasis is on short rather then efficient code
- oh yeah almost forgot... good luck!

Comment: Is it code-golf? If so, tag it. If not, define the winning criteria.

Comment: @ugoren sorry not sure where to draw the line, i want shortest within the criteria, is that challenge or golf?

Comment: What is the format of the string ? Does it have some special terminator (e.g. C-style NUL) ?

Comment: what should it say if they are both the same size? anything or blank?

Comment: @lalalalalalalambda you could do blank, its a technical loophole if i didnt specify it.

Comment: why the `-1` guys?

Comment: @PaulR if i dont specify, you can do whatever you want, as long as it fits the rules.

Comment: -1s are probably because your question is very unclear; you don't specify what format the strings are in, how to call the program, what the output should be, etc.

Comment: To Doorknob's comment I would add that questions of the form "Do a task that would normally be insanely trivial but with your hands cuffed behind your back" might make for amusing television, but in the context of programming challenges they largely come down to arguing that a particular language feature doesn't technically break the arbitrary restriction.

Comment: @PeterTaylor true, i didnt really think about that.

Comment: "no > / < (greater then/less then) inside if / if-else"  `while(a>b){ do_something(); break;}` is equivalent to an `if`...

Comment: @MrZander "and no cheating", obviously a run-once loop is not allowed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: To be fair, doing things with your hands cuffed behind your back is the reason I mostly golf in sed :P

Comment: No addition and subtraction, and no reproducing it? You can’t reasonably expect a number.

Comment: @minitech thats what code puzzles are all about...

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: Code puzzles still have to be possible. Every single answer here involves addition, by the way.

Comment: @minitech it can involve addition, and subtraction, just not in order to determine which is longer - you can still use it in a `printf` or whatever, see answer from @C5H8NNaO4 (my favorite here).

Comment: It’s your statement that “improvised addition/subtraction is not allowed” that makes this question really… open to debate. The top sed solution improvises addition and subtraction by doing it in unary. It’s still improvised, but it’s in a different base. How far do you have to “improvise” before it’s not against the rules?

Comment: @minitech: Actually, my sed solution only subtracts (in unary, as I'm removing pairs of letters on each side), though technically only string substitutions are used. It's might be an abuse of the rules (eg. since output wasn't specified, using unary "a" and "b", the remains of the string), but so are most of the other answers.

Comment: @Hasturkun: But you’re *adding a negative number*. Gosh. (See, I just don’t know where it’s supposed to end…)

Comment: [Relevant](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40469122#40469122)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### SED, 45 (43 + 2 for the -n flag)

```
s/./a/g
h
n
s/./b/g
G
:a
s/b\(.*\)a/\1/
ta
```

Expects input as two separate lines, outputs the difference in unary, using "a" or "b" to indicate the longer string. run with `sed -n`.

Answer (score 5):

### Tcl 8.6, 90

```
lmap c [split $a {}] d [split $b {}] {puts [expr {{}eq$d?{A}:{}eq$c?{B}:[continue]}];exit}
```

If you run Tcl 8.5, use `foreach` instead `lmap`.

This shows a nice feature of Tcl's foreach/lmap: It can walk over several lists at once.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>87</s> 78 - tells which is longer and by how much

alternative:

- 72 - tells which is longer and by how much, no special message if equal

---

Perl script expecting 2 strings as command line arguments. Tells which one is longer and by how much. This one I tried to make it readable and not short.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($x,$y)=@ARGV;
$x=$x=~s/.//g;
$y=$y=~s/.//g;
my @z=($x..$y);
my @w=($y..$x);
if (@z) {
    if ($#z) { print "2nd longer than 1st by $#z" }
    else { print "Equal length" }
}
else {
    print "1st longer than 2nd by $#w"
}
```

Same code as a one liner, counting 78 characters (output now prints "a3" if a > b by 3 characters, "0" if equal):

```
perl -E'($x,$y)=@ARGV;$_=s/.//g for$x,$y;@z=$x..$y;@w=$y..$x;say@z?$#z?"b$#z":0:"a$#w"'
```

Finally, since OP clarified that when they are equal it is not really important what it will print, we can save 6 more characters:

```
perl -E'($x,$y)=@ARGV;$_=s/.//g for$x,$y;@z=$x..$y;@w=$y..$x;say@z?"b$#z":"a$#w"'
```

Comment: You don't need to count the perl -e (or -E), or the single-quotes around the program, so yes, your score is currently 78.

Answer (score 4):

## J 17

Since there is no output specification: the length difference is outputted at the location of the shortest string

```
    longest =: *&.^/"1@(=&' ')@,:
    'foobar' longest 'abc'
0 3 NB. Means abc is shorter by 3 chars.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript <del>96</del> 92

```
x=prompt;i=c=0;for(p=x();c=p[i=-~i];);q=x();for(j=0;c=q[i=~-i,j=-~j];);alert(0<i&&p+i||q+-i)
```

*Note `0<i&&` contains no if statement but a logical operator, which is not forbidden.*

Input
  asd,asdfg
Output
  asdfg2

Means asdfg is 2 characters longer.

Comment: this is a fair loophole, and you program is cute.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? c=p[i=-~i] would just be 1 wouldn't it?

Comment: @tristin I'm on mobile, but i'll try: `~` is the bitwise NOT operator and flips all bits. `0001` becomes `1110`. So `~0 === -1` and `- -1 === 1` -> `~1 === -2` and `- -2 === 2` and so forth. I hope this was understandable :)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>66</s> 52 (shows only which one is longer)

```
f=->{gets.gsub(/./,?1)}
a=f[]
b=f[]
puts'sab'[a<=>b]
```

Prints `s` for same, `a` for string a, and `b` for string b.

## Ruby, <s>184</s> <s>173</s> <s>146</s> <s>143</s> <s>139</s> 140 (also shows how much longer it is)

```
f=->{gets.gsub(/./,?1)}
a=f[]
b=f[]
d=->e{Math.log10(e.to_i).floor.next.to_s}
puts(a==b ? ?s:(c=a.sub(b,''))!=a ? ?a+d[c]:?b+d[b.sub(a,'')])
```

Sample run:

```
c:\a\ruby>stringcmp
testing123
testing
a3

c:\a\ruby>stringcmp
codegolf.SE
code golf . stack exchange
b15

c:\a\ruby>stringcmp
test
test
s

c:\a\ruby>
```

Comment: second example contains `+`'s

Comment: @lalalalalalalambda For string concatenation, not addition.

Comment: OK, I removed mine thinking concatenation would also count as addition, requiring strings to be joined via adding/removing elements to an array... just nit-picking though because mine is so darn long :P I don't think there is any hard n fast rule about it

Comment: @Doorknob This `+` is *not* string concatenation: `Math.log10(e.to_i)+1` (second version, third line). You can use integer's `.next` or `.succ` though.

Comment: @daniero Whoops, missed that. Fixed (only +1 char)

Answer (score 3):

Bringing up the rear as always with the verbose language. :)

## Java - 278

```
import java.util.*;class b{public static void main(String[]a){Stack z=new Stack(),y=new Stack();for(String q:a[0].split(""))z.push(q);for(String q:a[1].split(""))y.push(q);while(!z.empty()&&!y.empty()){z.pop();y.pop();}System.out.print(y.empty()?"1-"+z.size():"2-"+y.size());}}
```

**With line breaks and tabs**

```
import java.util.*;
class a{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        Stack z=new Stack(),y=new Stack();
        for(String q:a[0].split(""))z.push(q);
        for(String q:a[1].split(""))y.push(q);
        while(!z.empty()&&!y.empty()){
            z.pop();
            y.pop();
        }
        System.out.print(y.empty()?"1-"+z.size():"2-"+y.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 40

```
f = #~Count~0 & /@ PadLeft[Characters /@ {##}] &
```

Output is similar to the J version.

**Example Usage:**

```
f["looooong", "short"]
```

> {0, 3}

```
f["short", "thisstringisveryverylong"]
```

> {19, 0}

```
f["equal", "equal"]
```

> {0, 0}

Answer (score 3):

### PHP (44)

```
-r'list(,$a,$b)=$argv;echo strcmp($a^$a,$b^$b);'
```

- The `-r` argument and single quotes are not counted in the score.
- *string-a* and *string-b* are accepted as command-line arguments.
- The magnitude of the decimal number printed is the difference in length.
- The sign indicates which string is longer. A positive number means *string-a* is longer. A negative number means *string-b* is longer. Zero means the strings are the same length.

### PHP 5.4 (96)

Here, `strcmp` is avoided in favor of other string functions that are not so cheap.

```
-r'list(,$a,$b)=$argv;echo@strtr(explode(${"\3"^$c=trim(($a^=$a).b^($b^=$b).a)},$$c,2)[1],"\0",$c);'
```

- Scoring and input format remain the same.
- The difference in length is printed in unary.
- The symbol `a`  is used if *string-a* is longer; `b` is used if *string-b* is longer.
- Nothing is printed if the strings are the same length (except in the commented version, which omits the error suppression operator `@` and thus may report PHP notices and warnings).

Commented code:

```
<?php

list(, $a, $b) = $argv;

// Replace all bytes in both $a and $b with null bytes
// (Anything XORed with itself is zero.)
$a ^= $a;
$b ^= $b;

// PHP's bitwise XOR truncates its output to the shorter string's length,
// so only the marker ('a' or 'b') appended to the shorter string will
// remain after the null bytes in common are trimmed off. If $a is shorter,
// 'b' remains; likewise, if $b is shorter, 'a' remains.
$longer = trim($a . 'b' ^ $b . 'a'); // $c in the golfed code

// Flip bits 0 and 1 to switch 'a' to 'b' (or 'b' to 'a')
// ('a' === chr(0b1100001); 'b' === chr(0b1100010); "\3" === chr(0b11))
$shorter = "\3" ^ $longer;

// Remove the shorter string from the longer string
// $$shorter refers to $a if $shorter === 'a' or $b if $shorter === 'b'.
// $$longer works the same way.
$difference = explode($$shorter, $$longer, 2)[1];

echo strtr($difference, "\0", $longer);
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (prompt for input) - 128

I golfed it 2 more characters.

```
p=prompt,f=alert,i='lastIndexOf'
a=p().replace(/./g,'.')
b=p().replace(/./g,'.')
j=a[i](b),k=b[i](a)
~j&&f('a '+j)
~k&&f('b '+k)
```

Comment: "this program has to **take two strings**"

Comment: You supply two strings a and b to a function F. Do you want command line style?

Comment: its not a stand-alone program, it doesnt matter how you get the strings, prompting or inputs or whatever is fine, it just has to be stand-alone.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - <strike>291</strike> <strike>261</strike> <strike>244</strike> <strike>223</strike> <strike>220</strike> <strike>210</strike> 206

I got 206

```
import sys,itertools
q=sys.argv
h=[]
i=0
for k,g in itertools.groupby(map(lambda f,b:2 if f is None else 1 if b is None else 0,q[1],q[2])):h.append(list(g))
for i,a in enumerate(h[1],1):0
print q[h[1][0]],i
```

### Sample Run

```
C:\pjs\codegolf>python last.py bananas apples
bananas 1
C:\pjs\codegolf>python last.py bananas hazlenuts
hazlenuts 2
```

Comment: Lots of room for golfing still. e.g. single-line blocks can go immediately after the colon on the previous line, like this: "if u:print [sys.argv[1],str(u)]". You can omit all of the indentation whitespace this way.

Comment: thanks @breadbox, I pinched this for mine, too. was trying `break if e` to no avail, so `if e:break` saved me another 12 :)

Comment: You can replace `pass` with `0` (or any other 1-character-Expression). Also, space after `,` and space before `[` is unnecessary. (On the other hand, you don't even need the brackets in the `print` statements.) Oh, and the calls to `list` should be unnecessary (untested). I'll stop now :-)

Comment: @WolframH I changed a little, but thank you about replace pass by 0

Comment: well done Doug and thanks to @WolframH, this CG thing is really educational!

Answer (score 2):

Bending the rules some...

### JavaScript (92)

```
p=prompt
~function f(a,b) {
   a && !b && alert(0)
  !a &&  b && alert(1)

  f(a.slice(1), b.slice(1))
}(p(),p())
```

(Minified: `p=prompt;~function f(a,b){a&&!b&&alert(0);!a&&b&&alert(1);f(a.slice(1),b.slice(1))}(p(),p())`)

Takes two strings via `prompt`s.  Alerts the difference in unary (as with Hasturkun's solution), using `0`s if the first string is longer and `1`s if the second string is longer.  Outputs each digit in a separate alert (ow), and terminates eventually when the call stack runs out (owww).

If we ignore the rule about no addition or subtraction, we could easily have the number be a nice (base 10) number whose sign denotes which string is longer:

```
p=prompt
alert(function f(a,b,n) {
  return a || b? f(a.slice(1), b.slice(1), n - !a + !b)
       :         n
}(p(),p(),0))
```

This version doesn't even wait for the call-stack to overflow!

Answer (score 2):

**Perl, 69 characters**

```
sub l{l(map{substr$_,1}@_)if$_[0]&&$_[1];say pop()?2:1;die}l(<>,<>)
```

The gist is, recurse until one string is empty, then print the other. Run with `perl -e CODE 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: <strike>125</strike> <strike>91</strike> 90

Finally beat the JavaScript solutions :)

Prints both which is longer, and by how much.

**Current (90 and Python 3):**

```
I=input
q=a,b=I(),I()
while a+b:s=q[b!=""];a=a[1:];b=b[1:];i=a and b and-1or-~i
print(s,i)
```

Example output:

```
rees@Rees-Ubuntu:~/Python/CodeGolf$ python3 StringComparer.py
hi <- input one
hello <- input two
hello 3 <- output
```

**Old (125 and Python 2):**

```
r=raw_input
q=a,b=r(),r()
while a and b:a=a[1:];b=b[1:]
s=(q[0],q[1])[a==""]
i=0
while a or b:a=a[1:];b=b[1:];i=-~i
print s,i
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <del>708</del>, <del>570</del>, <del>566</del>, <del>462</del>, <del>492</del>, <del>481</del>, <del>480</del>, <del>475</del>, <del>363</del>, <del>357</del>, <del>354</del>, <del>346</del>, <del>343</del>, <del>341</del>, <del>340</del>, <del>327</del>, 315 (with whitespace)

My first CG, be gentle:

```
import sys
c=[1,2]
a=o=[]
l=d=e=v=0
s=sys.argv
r=range(0,99)
a=[zip(list(s[x]),r[1:]) for x in c]
a.insert(0,0)
for x in c:
    for p in a[x]:
        try:
            v=a[x==2 and 1 or 2][p[1]]
        except:
            l=s[x]
            o.append(1)
            e=1
    if e:break
o=zip(o,r)
print[l,o.pop()[1]]
```

**Sample run:**

```
me@home:~$ python diff.py bananas apples
['bananas', 1]
me@home:~$ python diff.py bananas hazlenuts
['hazlenuts', 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**C, <strike>230</strike> <strike>200</strike> 193 characters**

**EDIT: Shortened it from 230 to 193 characters.**

My first golf attempt. Maybe not a hole-in-one, but it works. Not being allowed to use strlen for this forces it to be fairly verbose in C. Maybe it can be shortened a bit?

```
a,b,w,i,l;
int main(int c,char **v){
    for(;a<256||b<256;i++){
        if(!v[1][i])a|=256;
        if(!v[2][i])b|=256;
        if(!(a&256))a++;
        if(!(b&256))b++;
    }
    a&=255;b&=255;
    w=a>b?0:1;
    l=w?b-a:a-b;
    printf("%s %i\n",v[w+1],l);
}
```

Or the uglier version:

```
a,b,w,i,l;int main(int c,char **v){for(;a<256||b<256;i++){if(!v[1][i])a|=256;if(!v[2][i])b|=256;if(!(a&256))a++;if(!(b&256))b++;}a&=255;b&=255;w=a>b?0:1;l=w?b-a:a-b;printf("%s %i\n",v[w+1],l);}
```

Example output:

```
N:\>golf.exe everything works
everything 5
```

Comment: it has to tell you how much it is longer **by** not how long the longer one is.

Comment: Some tips: `int` in variable declarations is optional. No need for parentheses around `a<256`. `if(!x)y` -> `x||y`. `i` is initialized by default.

Comment: Whoops, it outputs the difference now instead. Thanks for the tips ugoren. I knew "i" was initialized too, but I'm just so used to trying to write clear code! Like I said, my first golf. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell 140**
*(assumes a max difference of 999)*

```
$c=@(compare($args[0]-split'.')($args[1]-split'.'))
$n=[collections.stack]@(999..1)
$c|%{$n.pop()}
if($c){$args[$c[0].sideindicator-eq'=>']}
```

Outputs nothing if the string lengths are equal. If the string lengths are not equal, the longer string is displayed; the last number is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 89 bytes

```c
i;c;q;j;f(a,b)char*a,*b;{for(i=j=c=0;a[i]||b[j];a[i]&&++i,b[j]&&++j)a[i]&&b[j]?:++c;a=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BbsIwEETvfMXWFSghrtQzVsSllbiD1APhsHbWsFFiQ5yqB@DbUztURbLk2Tc7ozVvR2PGkZVRF9Uom6HUuTlhv0S51OpqfZ9x2ZSmfFe458PtpvfNYZKLRVGwTGNSTf5gaV6visIoLI26j681WXYEu8/tbiqHc89usJn4YGupJ2cINA0/RA4qMQ@VAHT1n1zBnCsnJKAELSGdBzrP1SxWQIfsshyus6lbDCcOEN/lmweC1rtjzInQ@VbEwGPHO59gQxBPChi3zxiedsCOplD6/2kiGGz9JBtqWy/hy/dt/ZLsZN3HXw) I think this has room for improvement, but I'm not sure where. Abuses undefined behaviour, but it it Works On TIO™. Simply starts increment `c` when one of `a[i]` or `b[j]` is the null byte (the end of the string); `i` and `j` are incremented until they hit this null byte.

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEITveYqtSoJ/VOi5wrcWck@ghziHlbxK1thSYrn0EOfZXcktDQg0@83OsOblZMw8szLqqlplM5Q6N2ccCpSFVjfrh4yrtjLVq8IDHyd9aI@L2mzKkmUak2rzxIo0TlNZGoWVUff5uSHLjmD/sdsv1XAZ2I02E@9sLQ3kDIGm8ZvIQS3WoRaArvmTb7Dm2gkJKEFLSMeBznO1ihXQI7ssh9tq6RbjmQPEd/3ikaDz7hRzIvS@EzHwu@OdT7AliCcFjNsXDA87YE9LKP3/NBEMtnmQLXWdl/Dph655Snay7vMP "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure - 206**

```
(defn is-longer [first second first-left second-left]
  (defn remaining [current count]
    (if (empty? current)
      (/ (Math/log count) (Math/log 2))
      (remaining (rest current) (bit-shift-left count 1))))
  (cond
   (empty? first-left) [2 (remaining second-left 1)]
   (empty? second-left) [1 (remaining first-left 1)]
   :else (is-longer first second (rest first-left) (rest second-left))))
```

Or minified:

```
(defn y [a b al bl] (defn x [u t] (if (empty? u) (/ (Math/log t) (Math/log 2)) (x (rest u) (bit-shift-left t 1)))) (cond (empty? al) [2 (x bl 1)] (empty? bl) [1 (x al 1)] :else (y a b (rest al) (rest bl))))
```

Or in prettierific:

Returns:
  [1|2 count]

Getting around not using + was a fun challenge.

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 194**

```
import sys,itertools as T
A=sys.argv
B=[]
N,i=None,0
for k,g in T.groupby(map(lambda f,b:[[0,1][b is N],2][f is N],A[1],A[2])):B.append(list(g))
for i,j in enumerate(B[1],1):0
print A[B[1][0]],i
```

Answer (score 0):

### R - 120/114

Shows difference:

```
a=strsplit(scan(what='c'),"")
c=0
for(i in 1:2){for(y in a[[i]]){if(i-1)c=c+1 else c=c-1}}
d=abs(c)
cat(a[[(c==d)+1]],d)
```

Shows just the longer:

```
a=strsplit(scan(what='c'),"")
c=0
for(i in 1:2){for(y in a[[i]]){if(i-1)c=c+1 else c=c-1}}
cat(a[[(c==abs(c))+1]])
```